# Which part of the code checks if the user is logged in on Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I need to change the way of verifying the logged user so that instead of using a session, use a verification of a token sent in the url. The problem is that I can't find which part of the code that checks if a user is logged in when accessing the Mediawiki.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This sounds like a major security risk. Furthermore, a session would still be required if you want the user to stay logged in.

Comment: My company wants the authentication to be through a token generated by an api, integrated into an ERP system. Ideally, check if the token is valid and then display the wiki page.

Comment: You might be able to use the SessionManager for that, but it sounds like something thay wouldn't be well supported.

Comment: I just can't find which part of the SessionManager I could change for that.